# I have this error code ORA-00942 when creating this table

Tags: oracle

I tried creating this table after writing the code.
There is no syntax error, but when I try to execute it, an error appears:

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>   00942. 00000 - "table or view does not exist"

What could it be I am doing wrong?

[image: Here is a screenshot of the error]

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please don't post links to images.  Just edit the question and paste in as text.   You are getting this error because one or more of the tables you are referencing in your constraint declarations has either not had the proper grants or synonyms created for access by the oracle user you are logged in as.

Comment: I would guess it's because your `FK_LOCNO` foreign key is trying to reference `LOACTION` - looks like that should probably be `LOCATION`?

Comment: I did notice the error came from spelling as @Alex Poole suggested but when i corrected it it returned another error this time " ORA-02264: name already used by an existing constraint
02264. 00000 -  "name already used by an existing constraint"
*Cause:    The specified constraint name has to be unique.
*Action:   Specify a unique constraint name for the constraint.

Comment: If you're getting ORA-02264, that means one of your constraint names already exists in the database. For example, if another table has a constraint called `FK_LOCNO` you can't name it the same for this table.